# traverse JSON - matching JSON elements to DOM elements?

Tags: jquery, json, dom, getjson, traversal

How to traverse JSON, looping through the DOM and JSON for matching json elements to elements in the DOM?

I have html:

```
<div class="input alpha grid_4">
<label for="enterEmail">Email Address<label>
<input id="enterEmail"  name="enterEmail" type="text" />
<span class="validMark"></span>
</div>
```

How I want it after the json rendering:

```
<div class="input alpha grid_4">
<label for="enterEmail">Email Address <a class="toolTip" href="#" title=" By providing us with an email address for your user name, you are more likely to remember it."></a></label>
<input id="enterEmail"  name="enterEmail" type="text" />
<span class="validMark"></span>
<div class="helperText">john@test.com</div>
</div>
```

And the json:

```
[
     {
           “field”:  “enterEmail”,
           “contextHelpText”:  “By providing us with an email address for your user name, you are more likely to remember it.”,
           “helperText”:  “john@test.com”
     },
     {
           “field”:  “billAddress1”,
           “contextHelpText”:  “Please enter the address associated with your billing information.” 
     }
]
```

I’m having problems conceptualizing how the loop would run, and if helpertext or contexHelpText don't exist in the json, how to account for that. (would it be better to have them in the json, but with no value?)

Comment: The question is, what to loop[, what part is fully dynamic?  I'm assuming the JSON data, but it could be the other way around.  This question needs a better explination, please.

Comment: @SpYk3HH - I want to use the json to append elements to the DOM. The json will be a full list of all of the form elements, specifying the contextHelp and the helperText, if they exist, to the field in the DOM specified by the json - "field"

Comment: in that case I would modify the answer given by Amadan and build in the order desired in end result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with is after a lot of input and other questions on SO.

```
function addInfoHTML(data) {

    if (typeof data != 'undefined' && data.length > 0) {
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            var $fieldDom = $('#' + data[i].field);
            //make sure field dom exists
            if ($fieldDom.length > 0) {
                var parentDiv = $fieldDom.parents('div.input');

                if (typeof data[i].contextHelpText != 'undefined') {
                    //find the first label from the input.div
                    var fieldLabel = $(parentDiv).find('label'),
                        $fieldLabel = $(fieldLabel),
                        ancHtml = " <a class='toolTip' href='#' alt='" + data[i].contextHelpText + "' title='" + data[i].contextHelpText + "'>some val</a>";

                    //append fieldLabel text(Enter Email) + ancHtml (tooltip)
                    $fieldLabel.html($fieldLabel.text() + ancHtml);
                }

                if (typeof data[i].helperText != 'undefined') {
                    var helperDiv = "<div class='helperText'>" + data[i].helperText + "</div>";
                    //append the helperDiv html at the end
                    $(parentDiv).append(helperDiv);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


//on document ready call the addInfoHtml by passing json data
$(function(){
    addInfoHTML(data);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var numFields = jsonData.length;
var i, field, $field, $helper;
for (var i = 0; i < numFields; i++) {
  field = jsonData[i];
  $field = $(field.field);
  if (field.contextHelpText) {
    $field.attr('title', field.contextHelpText);
  }
  $helper = $field.parent().children('.helperText');
  if ($helper && field.helperText) {
    $helper.html(field.helperText);
  }
}
```

Messy, but can't do better with your requirements.

Comment: Hey Amadan, what do you mean - and can I elaborate on anything to clear up my question?

Comment: Just the fact that `.helperText` is so structurally unconnected with the field in which `helperText` should reside; I'd probably also unify the names of the JSON fields with the names of the HTML attributes they go to.

Comment: Would it make sense to have the container div have an id, for direction purposes?

Comment: Meh... I don't know. If you can promise yourself `.helperText` will always be somewhere you can write a generally applicable accessor for (like `$field.parent().children('.helperText')` here), it's fine. It works. :p

Comment: well, helpertext will exist on some fields and not others - wondering how to build this out appropriately

Comment: That's fine, as long as it's always accessible with the same selector when present.

Comment: and would pure.js serve any purpose here?

Comment: It could, if you build it to do so. :p

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like: ??? ([**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/SpYk3/gJ7Mf/))

```
$(function() {
    var jDat = [
        {
            "field":  "enterEmail",
            "label":  "Enter Email",
            "contextHelpText":  "By providing us with an email address for your user name, you are more likely to remember it.",
            "helperText":  "john@test.com"
        },
        {
            "field":  "billAddress1",
            "label":  "Bill Address 1",
            "contextHelpText":  "Please enter the address associated with your billing information." 
        }
    ];

    for (i=0;i<jDat.length;i++) {
        var newDiv = $("<div />").addClass("input alpha grid_4"), // or could draw from json data on if statemtn for the classes
            newDat = jDat[i];

        if (newDat['field']) {
            var newLbl = $("<label />").attr("for", newDat.field).text(newDat.label).appendTo(newDiv), // you'll need to add data for label of each field
                newInp = $("<input />").attr({ id: newDat.field, name: newDat.field, type: "text" }).appendTo(newDiv);
                newSpn = $("<span />").addClass("validMark").appendTo(newDiv)

            if (newDat['contextHelpText']) newLbl.append($("<a />").attr({ href: 'javascript:void(0)', title: newDat.contextHelpText }).addClass("toolTip"));
            if (newDat['helperText']) newDiv.append($("<div />").addClass("helperText").text(newDat.helperText));

            $("#contentArea").append(newDiv);
        };
    };
});​
```

Comment: Looks good, except that the field and label already exist in the html. That's the trick.

Comment: can you provide more of an example? maybe a jsfiddle or a sandbox link of some sort? i mean, if the json data is dynamic, how can the html already be there? i'm confused as to the route you intend to take